# Why doesn't background-position affect my gradient?

Tags: css, css-animations, background-position

I wanted to make simple CSS3 animation for a loading bar. I used `repeating-linear-gradient` to make some angled stripes. I would like them to move forward infinitely.

```css
div {

    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-40deg, #bf2e38 0em, #a42830 0.01em, #a42830 2em,#bf2e38  2em, #bf2e38 4em); 
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 5s linear infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 0%}
    100%{background-position:100% 0%}
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

But in my browser it shows as static object.

Curiously, it works when I use an image as background instead:

```css
div {

    background-image: url("https://caniuse.com/img/browserstack.svg");

    background-position: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 5s linear infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 0%}
    100%{background-position:100% 0%}
}
```

```html
<div>Test using icon</div>
```

So how to animate the gradient the way image is animated? Why does browser ignore `background-position`?

Comment: using % all the positon are equivalent because the size is by default 100% .. change the background size and it will start moving

Comment: check this : https://css-tricks.com/i-like-how-percentage-background-position-works/

Comment: and this : https://www.sitepoint.com/css-using-percentages-in-background-image/

Comment: I agree with @TemaniAfif you should change the size

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for the explanation! The linked answer solves the problem, but doesn't explain it.

Comment: yes wasn't able to find the duplicate I needed ... not easy :p .By the way the explanation you need are within the links I shared ;)